# Unable to install Subversive connectors (SVN) on Eclipse Neon

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subversive

I installed the new Eclipse Neon, then added the Subversive plugIn (for SVN) but have strange issue to add SVN connectors.

What I do:
1. Window -> Preference -> Team -> SVN.
2. On the "SVN Connector" tab I click on "Get Connectors...".
3. Checking the box for "SVN Kit 1.8.12" and click "finish" (tried also checking Native JavaHL instead).
4. On the new window, I leave both connectors checked and click on "next" and then on "Finish" ("Subversive SVN Connectors" and "SVNKit 1.8.12 Implementation (Optional))".

After 1 second I got the following error message:

> 'Installing Software' has encountered a problem.
>   An error occured while collecting items to be installed.

Details:

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
>   session context was:(profile=C__Users_michaels_eclipse_java-neon_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
>   No artifact repository available.
>   noArtifactRepositoriesAvailable

I tried to add/remove update sites but it didn't help.

Someone familiar with this issue?
Should I install other Eclipse (Luna?)

Thanks in advance! 
Mike

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing the same process on another fresh Eclipse Neon installation? I've had problems with this and the only way I found to make it work was a fresh install from a new Eclipse.

If nothing else works, try Eclipse Mars, I use it at work with Subversive and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. To install subversive on Neon (at the time of writing neon-3):

1. Select Help > Install New Software
2. In the Work With field enter:  http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon
3. In the Filter Text field enter: svn
4. Install the software as usual and restart.
5. When Eclipse restarts, open Window > Preferences.
6. Select Team > SVN and you should be prompted to download the SVN Connectors (SVNKit 1.8.14 worked for me). Install as usual and restart. Now Subversive should work.